# Checking string for words in list stored in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing a list of strings in a column called `contains_and`. Now I want to select the rows from that dataframe whose words in `contains_and` are *all* contained in a given string, e.g.

```py
example: str = "I'm really satisfied with the quality and the price of product X"

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"columnA": [1,2], "contains_and": [["price","quality"],["delivery","speed"]]})
```

resulting in a dataframe like this:

```
   columnA       contains_and
0        1   [price, quality]
1        2  [delivery, speed]
```

Now, I would like to only select row 1, as `example` contains all words in the list in `contains_and`.

My initial instinct was to do the following:

```py
df.loc[
    all([word in example for word in df["contains_and"]])
    ]
```

However, doing that results in the following error:

`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`

I'm not quite sure how to best do this, but it seems like something that shouldn't be all too difficult. Does someone know of a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
df = df[df.contains_and.apply(lambda x: all((i in example) for i in x), 1)]
```

OUTPUT:

```
   columnA      contains_and
0        1  [price, quality]
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)ing the list of candidate words and checking (per row) if they are all in the words of `example` which are found with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
# a Series of words
ex = pd.Series(example.split())

# boolean array reduced with `all`
to_keep = df["contains_and"].explode().isin(ex).groupby(level=0).all()

# keep only "True" rows
new_df = df[to_keep]
```

to get

```
>>> new_df

   columnA      contains_and
0        1  [price, quality]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Nk03 answer, you could also try:

```
df = df[df.contains_and.apply(lambda x: any([q for q in x if q in example]))]
```

In my opinion is more intuitive to check if words are in example, rather than the opposite, as your first attempt shows.